# Wordpress can't upload a file using the native file uploader when editing media

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-media

When editing a post on Wordpress, I am attempting to upload an image from the Edit post screen. a small Image icon opens the pane which gives me three options: Upload, Media Library, Insert from URL. it looks like this:

[image]

When I choose Upload, and choose an image, I get

[image]

Unfortunately, for me, this is caused by the upload endpoint returning bad content. it seems to return BOTH an HTML redirection notice (not a real redirect, just a notice telling the user the media has moved), and then it contains the JSON response AFTEr the close of the body tag.

see both pictures

[image]

**Notice that after the redirection notification there's the JSON for the media that was just created.**

[image]

I am on Wordpress 5.3.2 and I am using the "WP Offload Media Lite" plugin which might be related but in fact I saw the problem when the plugin was not installed so I think it might not be related.

I am using only a basic set of other plugins, like Akismet, Contact Form, Insert Headers & footers, and WP Mail SMTP. I have only a basic theme chosen (but I don't think that's the problem)

Comment: has been cross-posted to WP Support forum https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-cant-upload-a-file-using-the-native-file-uploader-when-editing-media/

Answer (score 0):

some answers I found on the internet

• this person suggests problems happen when your media filename have spaces

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-response-is-not-a-valid-JSON-response-in-WordPress

• This Wordpress support topic is closed for commenting and offers no solution other than use the Health check, which does me no good

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response-2/

• This non-developer WordPress user suggests some work-arounds which are simply to use the other way to upload media into your WordPress site:

https://navinrao.com/the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response

these might be good answers but it seems to me the problem is a bug